Are these tales of Vali's prowess canonical?
https://www.thehindu.com/society/faith/when-vali-roused-ramas-ire/article67630242.ece

When Rama and Lakshmana arrive at the Rishyamukha Hill and meet Vali’s brother Sugriva, they notice the absence of Sugriva’s wife. Vaali is an ardent devotee of Siva and his devotion is coupled with immense strength. When the devas and asuras became tired while churning the milky ocean, Vali stepped up and churned with such might that the nectar was secured soon. Being a devotee of Siva, Vali travelled in all eight directions to offer his prayers. On one occasion, when he was praying, Ravana, who was on a digvijayam, irritated the ape. Vali tied up his ten heads with his tail and scampered all over the world, even stopping over his son Angada’s cradle and waving the tied heads of Ravana like a toy. Ravana wisely kept away from Vali’s kingdom after that.

